# Map a table to the appropriate ActiveRecord::Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to loop through all of my Database tables and iterate through each record in my Database. I'm achieving this currently like so:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|

  table.classify.constantize.find_each do |record|
  end

  rescue NameError
end
```

The problem is that it pulls table like this: `ar_internal_metadata` and `schema_migrations` which don't have corresponding models so, therefore, my `table.classify.constantize` fails with a `NameError` which is why I'm rescuing that at the bottom.

I'd like to not have to rescue that error. So, is there a way I can map a table to the appropriate ActiveRecord::Model?

Answer (score 1):

Just ignoring all non-existing models is error prone. Instead, I suggest to only ignore tables you expect not to have a corresponding model.

```
RAILS_META_TABLES = %w[ar_internal_metadata schema_migrations]

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
  next if RAILS_META_TABLES.include?(table)

  table.classify.constantize.find_each do |record|
    # ...
  end
end
```